# UWP Button Hover Background not changed

Tags: button, uwp, background-image, mousehover

```
 <Button x:Name="btn" Tag="{x:Bind Id}" Click="btn_Click" Width="35" Height="40" ClickMode="Press" Margin="540,0,0,-18">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Border x:Name="Border">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Image x:Name="NormalBackground" Source="Assets/NextSmall.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                                    <Image x:Name="HoverBackground"  Source="Assets/NextBig.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                    <Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Source="Assets/NextBig.png" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
```

Hello I want the background image to change when I hover over the button. But it doesn't change.

Platform : UWP

Version : 17763

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

When I delete the code above, the picture comes up but the normal picture is not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Button Hover Background not changed

The problem is the button's content is empty, so it can't detect `PointerOver` event when the cursor is point over. For solve this problem please fill the content with `Transparent` Rectangle for button like the following.

```
<Button
    x:Name="btn"
    Width="60"
    Height="60"
    Margin="540,0,0,-18"
    Click="btn_Click"
    ClickMode="Press"    
    >
    <Button.Content>
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="60" Width="60"/>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Template>
```